# Site title with php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to set the HTML `<title>` to data queried from a MySQL database.  However I am getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in
>   /home/acamate/public_html/farkc.com/index.php on line 6

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
$db1 = $pdo->query("SELECT sitename FROM config WHERE=1");
?>
<title><?php print_r($db1); ?></title>
```

connect.php:

```
<?php 
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test'; $user = 'test'; $password = 'test';
    try {
        $db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $db->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
?>
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Can you show connect.php code ?

Comment: As the error message says, `$pdo` is not an object. Are you sure your code in `connect.php` successfully creates an object and stores it in `$pdo`?

Comment: 'code' <?php

$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test';
$user = 'test';
$password = 'test';
 
try {
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$db->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

?>

Comment: You var should be `$db` and not `$pdo`

Comment: now the site is working  but <title> is blank

Comment: You still need to fetch the result of your query ( http://www.mustbebuilt.co.uk/php/select-statements-with-pdo/ )

Comment: `<?php
include('connect.php');
$sql= "SELECT sitename FROM config"; 
$stmt = $pdo->query($sql); 
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $row['sitename'];
?>
<title><?php echo $row->sitename; ?></title>`


I try this but same error again "Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/acamate/public_html/farkc.com/index.php on line 5"

Comment: Why every give negative rating? i dont understand this site members. if i can find answer of this, i dont post. 

you can see after helps we couldnt solve the problem. so you can see this this not very easy problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up your variable names.  Try the following

```
<?php
  include('connect.php');
  $stmt = $db->query("SELECT sitename FROM config WHERE=1");
  $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
<title><?php echo $row['sitename']; ?></title>
```

You where using `$pdo` instead of `$db` but `$pdo` was never defined or instantiated.

Comment: same error :(

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in /home/acamate/public_html/farkc.com/index.php on line 5

------------------------------
line 5 is ->   $row1 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Comment: That's a different error, we have moved in the right direction.  Try `var_dump()` on `$stmt`

Comment: Is it still not working?  For some reasons `$stmt` is not being set.

Comment: I am not sure how can i use var_dump() but i use like this

`<?php
  include('connect.php');
  $stmt = $db->query("SELECT sitename FROM config WHERE=1");
  var_dump($stmt);
  $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
<title><?php echo $row['sitename']; ?></title>`

Comment: and now show this -> bool(false) 
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in /home/acamate/public_html/farkc.com/index.php on line 6

Comment: OK that's good, put this line of code `die(var_export($db->errorinfo(), TRUE))` in immediately after your `$stmt = $db->query();` line.

Comment: now blank page. last version is 
`<?php
  include('connect.php');
  $stmt = $db->query("SELECT sitename FROM config WHERE=1"); die(var_export($db->errorinfo(), TRUE))
  var_dump($stmt);
  $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
<title><?php echo $row['sitename']; ?></title>`

Comment: change line to `var_export($db->errorinfo(), TRUE)` (get rid of the `die()`).  And put this code at the very top of your PHP script.  It should be the first thing to run. `ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: again blank page :(

`<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1); ini_set('display_startup_errors',1); error_reporting(-1);
  include('connect.php');
  $stmt = $db->query("SELECT sitename FROM config WHERE=1"); var_export($db->errorinfo(), TRUE)
  var_dump($stmt);
  $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
<title><?php echo $row['sitename']; ?></title>`

Comment: Not sure what is happening.

Comment: you know that in HTML, the `<title>` does not show up on the page, but rather is shown by the browser in the window title or something like that.
so you have to check the generated HTML.

Comment: I fixed today :) these codes now working. thank you for your help

`
`<?php
  include('connect.php');
  $stmt = $db->query("SELECT sitename FROM config WHERE id=1");
  $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
<title><?php echo $row['sitename']; ?></title>`